# JavaScript(react project dark mode)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can somebody tell me how to select ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb with javascript?

I want to create a darkMode of the webpage and i would like to set up a different scrollbar for white and dark mode.

I'm using ::-webkit-scrollbar-track, ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb selectors to change the scrollbar in css but i would like to change the css property based on my isDarkMode state.

For Example: If it's dark mode the scrollbar color is darkPurple with black background, if it's white mode then lightPurple color with white background.

So far the only working code i found is this.But the addRule method is deprecated.

```
if (isDarkMode) {
      document.styleSheets[0].addRule("::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb", "background: #E100A4") &&
        document.styleSheets[0].addRule("::-webkit-scrollbar-track", "background: #141414")
    } else {
      document.styleSheets[0].addRule("::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb", "background: #964EFF") &&
        document.styleSheets[0].addRule("::-webkit-scrollbar-track", "background: #FFF")
    }
```

Second option:

```
<div className={`${isDarkMode ? 'scrollbarDark' : 'scrollbarWhite'} h-screen overflow-y-scroll`}>
```

Since i added h-screen the scroll eventlistener is not working anymore, and i need that to change the navbar based on scroll.

Thank you everybody in advance!

Comment: Or... you can use CSS custom properties to do that.

Comment: make your life easier and start using tailwindcss

Comment: i tried to add something like .whiteScrollBar ::webkit-scroll-thumb{} css and add the whiteScrollBar class to my upper <div> but somehow it was not working.

Comment: i'm using tailwindcss for the rest of the page but still did not find a method to change the scrollbar

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change scrollbar when using Tailwind (next.js/react)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69400560/how-to-change-scrollbar-when-using-tailwind-next-js-react)

Comment: @Samathingamajig i managed to make that work, i think the overflow-y-scroll and the height had to be set ( i missed those), but now it looks like the eventlistener for scroll is not working anymore after i added the overflow-y-scroll, any idea why?